# How to print list item + integer/string using logging in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to print list item with the index of item such as

```
0: [('idx', 10), ('degree', 0)]
1: [('idx', 20), ('degree', 0)]
```

Based on the code below, how can I append '0:' as integer + string + list item?

```
import logging

class Node(object):
    __slots__= "idx", "degree"

    def __init__(self, idx, degree):
        self.idx = idx
        self.degree = 0


    def items(self):
        "dict style items"
        return [
            (field_name, getattr(self, field_name))
            for field_name in self.__slots__]

def funcA():

    a = []
    a.append(Node(10, 0))
    a.append(Node(20, 0))

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        logging.debug(a[i].items())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  
    funcA()
```

Currently, result is

```
DEBUG:root:[('idx', 10), ('degree', 0)]
DEBUG:root:[('idx', 20), ('degree', 0)]
```

Expecting

```
DEBUG:root:0:[('idx', 10), ('degree', 0)]
DEBUG:root:1:[('idx', 20), ('degree', 0)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this.

```
def funcA():
    a = []
    a.append(Node(10, 0))
    a.append(Node(20, 0))

    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        message = '%s:%s' % (i, a[i].items())
        logging.debug(message)
```

Which produces this as output:

```
DEBUG:root:0:[('idx', 10), ('degree', 0)]
DEBUG:root:1:[('idx', 20), ('degree', 0)]
```

You could also use join:

```
message = ':'.join([str(i), str(a[i].items())])
```

Or format:

```
message = '{0}:{1}'.format(str(i), a[i].items())
```

Whatever is the most clear to you.

Answer (score 10):

with Python > 3.6 you can use [fstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
logging.debug(f"{i}:{a[i].items()}")
```